# How do these characters (%25u, %25U) in a URL, pose a security risk?

Tags: encoding, url

I was reviewing some SiteMinder APACHE 2.2 WebAgent configuration files when I came across '`%25u,%25U`' in the list of ASCII/URL-encoded characters in the attribute `badurlchars` as below:

```
[Wed Jun 19 2013 05:04:14] badurlchars='//,./,/.,/*,*.,~,\,%00-%1f,%7f-%ff,%25u,%25U'.
```

> Basically the WebAgent will reject any request that contains the above
>   characters in the URL occurring before the `'?'` character.

Now I know that the `badurlchars` attribute can contain the ASCII characters itself or the URL-encoded form of that character. [[SiteMinder reference]](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r6%200%20SP6-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/index.htm?toc.htm?258201.html)

So what does '`%25u,%25U`' signify in this case and why are they being placed in this list?
I guess finding out how these pose a security risk would also indirectly answer my question.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I came across [this Debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=654863) that talks about a bug in `xdg-open` where URLs containing ampersands are parsed and an ampersand is converted into `%u` which then gets encoded into `%25u`. Now I am no Debian expert but could this be a security flaw that it would make sense to block `%25u` in a URL?

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I got a response saying that **the characters `%25u`/`%25U` refer to the ASCII Device Control Character [EM (End Of Medium)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_Medium#EM)**.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp):

```
ASCII Character:  EM
HTML Entity Code: &#25;
Description:      end of medium
```

---

> **Quick note:** ASCII character **`%`** (**`37`** in decimal) is represented as **`%25`**
>   (hexadecimal) after [percent
>   encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).
>   [[Reference1]](http://web.forret.com/tools/charmap.asp?show=ascii) [[Reference2]](http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/introduction-to-url-encoding-url-encoded-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking at is an attempt to defeat a [Canonicalization Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization) where an attacker attempts to embed encoded characters into a URL or other input value, such that it may be missed by security filters, read into the system, decoded, and then used for ill intent. these kinds of attacks are usually used to navigate to places that should not be accessible or inject bad input.

see more here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Canonicalization,_locale_and_Unicode

Comment: it might be slightly broader... I found this https://github.com/arnemart/SafariKeywordSearch/issues/13 where %25u is used in a Youtube search to force a search for a Japanese text character, via the hex code for the Unicode version of the Japanese text... and %25u is what the search string needs to decode the hex